# Maven will not find junit tests to execute, says it ran 0 tests and the build succeeded

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit

Firstly, why does maven come with a `test` goal, but also I see people running `mvn surefire:test` as if it does something else. What is the difference between the two?

Secondly, I cannot seem to get maven to run my unit tests. No matter what I try, I always get `Results : Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0` . My `myproject/target/generated-tests-sources/test-annotations` directory is empty, but my `myproject/target/test-classes` directory contains a `.class` file for each of my test classes.

**Project Structure:**

- `myproject/src/main/java/MyClass.java`
- `myproject/src/test/java/MyClassTest.java`
- `myproject/pom.xml`

**Sample MyclassTest.java Content:**

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class MyClassTest {
    @Test
    void testFunction() {
        assertEquals(0, 0);
    }
}
```

**Contents of `pom.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>co.blocanse.pa.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Output of `mvn compile`**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myproject 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 7 source files to D:\projects\myproject\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.141 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-01T23:32:27-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/213M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Output of `mvn test`**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myproject 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ myproject  ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ myproject  ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ myproject  ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ myproject  ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to D:\projects\myproject\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ myproject  ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: D:\projects\myproject\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.362 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-01T23:38:07-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/213M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here's where the issue lies. I would expect the test results to say that it ran 1 test, but it claims it went through and ran none of them, while still succeeding the build. `mvn surefire:test` yields the same outcome. My apologies for the large amount of copy-pasted content, but I want to provide as much information as possible because I'm not sure what to try next. If it helps, I'm on Windows and using IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` is junit 5 (which may not be supported fully yet), and not junit 4.   Remove the jupiter dependency and use junit 4 for now.  A sample jUnit 4 test from https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/getting-started:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CalculatorTest {
  @Test
  public void evaluatesExpression() {
    Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
    int sum = calculator.evaluate("1+2+3");
    assertEquals(6, sum);
  }
}
```

Comment: trying this and will report back shortly if it works.

Comment: that was exactly it. Removing the `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` dependency from my tests and `pom.xml` did it. Thank you!